# Cardinality in phpmyadmin tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

plz how i can add many emission in programme table ..i have a problem with cardinality in phpmyadmin

[image: Click to see my database]

Comment: What kind of problem do you have in phpmyadmin? If I understat correct then picture is correct, but you can't get this in phpmyadmin?

Comment: i cant modify nombre of lignes to 1000 ..i have maximum 500

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite confused about the problem. This isn't phpMyAdmin, for one thing, and I see some link between emission and programme in the picture. What is it you're having trouble with? Which number of lines is limiting you to 500?